# What do memory configurations like "256Kx18" mean?

Tags: memory, flash, eeprom, sdram, sram

This is a beginner question here. When choosing memory ICs, one of the options is the memory size/configurations. I understand the size part, but what does the "16Kx9" mean? It seems the same memory size is usually available in different configurations. I attached a screenshot from Digikey as an example.

[image: example]

Comment: What hasn't been mentioned in the answers yet: if the configuration is some multiple of 9, it generally means that you're dealing with some combination of 8 bit bytes and 1 bit parity.

Comment: Usually, although there is no requirement to use it in that manner.

Comment: that's good point. thanks guys for your great answers - good karma :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

256K x 8 means 256 kibi-locations, each location holding 8 bits. There are 18 address lines (2<sup>18</sup> = 256 * 1024) and 8 data lines.

Answer (score 7):

16k x 9 means that the memory chip has a total of 16k locations in which it can store a binary number that consists of 9 bits. It will have a 14 bit address structure (14 bit gives you  16,384 locations in decimal). It may be a serial device but the address lines will still be there but internal to the device.

Comment: When you say it will have a 14-bit address structure, is this a common property of all memory or is it derived from the aforementioned `16k x 9` notation?

Comment: @JYelton \$2^{14}\$ = 16,384 and 16k (binary speak) is 16,384 and uses 14 address lines. Not sure I've answered your question?

Comment: I see it now, it's a matter of taking the number of locations (16k, which is 16,384) and knowing to what power 2 is raised to arrive at that figure. I was missing that, which made it seem like you magically came up with the number 14. :)

Comment: @JYelton a pleasure to help you sir!